# Physical meaning of Vector Calculus Corollaries

Tags: vectors, vector-fields, calculus

The divergence theorem and the Stokes theorem have well known physical interpretations.

For example, the divergence theorem merely states that the amount that a vector flows out through a closed surface is equal to the amount that the vector is produced all over the volume enclosed by the surface (or something similar. It is possible that my wording is wrong, but you get the idea.)

$$ \iiint_V \nabla \cdot {\bf v} \ d\tau = \iint_S {\bf v\cdot d\sigma} $$

Similar interpretations exist for Stokes theorem:
$$\oint _{\Gamma }\mathbf {F}  \cdot d{\mathbf {\Gamma } }=\iint _{S}\nabla \times \mathbf {F}  \cdot d\mathbf {S} $$ (Surface integral of the curl amounts to adding small loops throughout the surface, which cancel out everywhere except at the boundaries, leaving behind a line integral along the boundary of the surface)

But there are some corollaries that can be drawn from these theorems. For example, by replacing $\bf v$ by $T\bf c$ where $T$ is a scalar and $\bf c$ is a constant vector, gives

\begin{align*}
\nabla \cdot {\bf v} &= \nabla \cdot (T{\bf c})\\ 
&= (\nabla T)\cdot {\bf c}\ + T \ (\nabla \cdot {\bf c}) \\
&= (\nabla T)\cdot {\bf c}\\
\text{and}\\
\iiint_V (\nabla T)\cdot {\bf c} \ d\tau &= \iint_S T{\bf c\cdot d\sigma} \\ 
\implies  {\bf c} \cdot \iiint_V \nabla T \ d\tau &= {\bf c} \cdot \iint_S T{\bf  d\sigma}\\
\text{And since $\bf c$ was arbitrary, }
\end{align*}
$$\boxed {\iiint_V \nabla T \ d\tau = \iint_S T{\bf  d\sigma}}$$

which is a corollary. But what does it physically imply ? Is there any intuitive physical explanation? Griffiths lists some more corollaries (shown below). Is there some way to think about these operators and/or integrals so as to construct intuitive physical explanations for these equations?

[image: Griffiths Problem listing some corollaries]